# MyISAM table index file keep crashing on regular basis!

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-126

Table keep Crashing 
ERROR 126 (HY000): Incorrect key file for table './DB/Table.MYI'; try to repair it

It does get fixed by repair table but the problem is reoccurring!! and it's 5G table takes ~45mins to repair.

Comment: the tmp folder has a limit usually 2GB, try df -h to see it

Answer (score 1):

Check your slow query log for a long running query on table.
Make sure other process like "backup" isn't interrupting it!!